# invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker, frontend, vuetify.js

i´m trying to create input type text with `v-text-field` and in this input open `v-date-picker` but when i clicked in my input, in console i show any errors and warnings:

```
valid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected Array, String, got Boolean with value false.

[Vuetify] Value must be a String, got Boolean

found in

---> <VDatePicker>
       <VThemeProvider>
         <VMenu>
           <VForm>
```

I don´t know that i´m doing wrong or i can´t see my problem. I´m reading about this problem and i can see that my problem it´s that i miss any parameter, but i can´t show it. To do this text-field i´m doing a `v-menu` with `template v-text-field` and `v-date-picker` i will share with you all my relevant code.

```
<v-flex>
   <!-- FECHA INICIO -->
   <strong>{{ label }}</strong>
    <v-menu
      ref="dateMenu"
      v-model="dateMenu"
      :close-on-content-click="false"
      :nudge-right="40"
      transition="scale-transition"
      offset-y
      max-width="290px"
      min-width="290px"
      >
         <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-text-field
              clearable
              solo
              slot="activator"
              v-model="fecha_inicio"
              append-outer-icon="event"
              @blur="date = parseDate($event.value)"
              :rules="fechaReglas"
              v-on="on"
              @click:clear="limpiarDate()"
             ></v-text-field>
        </template>
        <v-date-picker 
           locale="es-ES"
           v-on="$listeners"
           first-day-of-week=1
           v-model="date" 
           no-title 
           :min="min"
           :max="max"
           @input="onDatePickerValueChanged" 
           >
       </v-date-picker>
    </v-menu>
  </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

In my script i have:

```
data () {
            return{
                id: null,
                valor: null,
                fecha_inicio: "",
                fecha_fin: "",
                anio: null,
                numeroLiquidacion: null,
                parametro_id: this.valorParametro.parametro_id,
                valorJSON: { },
                listaNumLiquidaciones: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
                fechaManual: false,
                dateFormatted: null,
                label: "Fecha Inicio",
                labelFin: "Fecha Fin",
                value: null,
                fechaReglas: [
                    value => {
                        const patern = /^(0[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[01])(\/)(0[1-9]|1[012])\2(\d{4})$/
                        if(this.fecha_inicio || this.fecha_fin) return patern.test(value) || 'No es un formato de fecha correcto, use dd/mm/yyyy'
                        else return true
                    }
                ],
                dateMenu: false,
                dateMenu2: false,
                date: false,
            }
        },

props: {
 ................
 min: { type: String, default: null },
 max: { type: String, default: null },
}

methods: {
    ..................
    parseDate (date) {
    
                    if (!date){
                        return null
                    } 
                    console.log(date)
                    let fecha = date.split('-')
    
                    return `${fecha[2]}/${fecha[1]}/${fecha[0]}`
                },
    
                limpiarDate(){
                    this.$emit('input', null);
                },
                onDatePickerValueChanged(date) {
                    console.log(date)
                    if (!date) return;
                    this.fecha_inicio = this.parseDate(date);
                    this.dateMenu = false;
                },
```

Thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I solve my problem. In ```date``` i had false. I need put ```null```

Comment: You can answer your own question or delete it. It would be great, if you answer yourself. Then you can accept you own answer and get points for this. ;-)